# DJANGO - Error creating Solr container (java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException)

Tags: python, django, docker

I'm trying to implement Solr in my Django project, but when I run the Solr container I get an AccessDenied error. Below are the container and haystack settings

local.yml

```
  solr:
  image: solr:7.7.1
  restart: always
  ports:
     - "8983:8983"
  volumes:
     - ./index/core:/opt/solr/server/solr/core
  environment:
      - SOLR_JAVA_MEM=-Xms512m -Xmx512m
      - SOLR_HEAP=512m
```

settings.py

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
"default": {
    "ENGINE": "haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine",
    "URL": env("SOLR_URL", default="http://0.0.0.0:8983/solr/core"),
    "SILENTLY_FAIL": False,
    "SOLR_TIMEOUT": 10
}
}
HAYSTACK_SIGNAL_PROCESSOR = "haystack.signals.RealtimeSignalProcessor"
```

error:

```
     SolrCore Initialization Failures
     core: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: 
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /opt/solr/server/solr/core/data
```